# Is there any water cooling kit for socket LGA 1151 with radiator/fan smaller than 120mm?

Tags: cooling, mini-pc

I was looking around online but I found the smaller models are 120mm.
Does any one know any model with a fan/radiator smaller than 120mm?

Comment: I think 120 mm is the smallest fan size they make for LGA 1151 water coolers. I can recommend more than a few 120 mm LGA 1151 water coolers if you like?

Comment: Any particular reason you need one this small?

Comment: No. I am wondering if they exist.